# Expressjs - Is there a way to have helper function with req,res object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to have a helper function for routes with the req,res object built into it. for eg. if I have send an error or success message in json I have the following lines of code

```
    console.log(err)
    data.success = false
    data.type = 'e'
    data.txt = "enter a valid email"
    res.json data
```

I am planning to put this in a helper function like this

```
global.sendJsonErr = (msg)->
        data.success = false
        data.type = 'e'
        data.txt = msg
        res.json data
```

But I don't have res object in the helper function how can I can get those objects, other than passing it around. As there would be moving more repeating code I would want to take out of the route.
It is more kind of macro rather than a function module.
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've written custom middleware to do similar things. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Adds the sendJsonErr function to the res object, doesn't actually execute it
  res.sendJsonErr = function (msg) {
    // Do whatever you want, you have access to req and res in this closure
    res.json(500, {txt: msg, type: 'e'})
  }

  // So processing can continue
  next() 
})
```

And now you can do this:

```
res.sendJsonErr('oh no, an error!')
```

See http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-write-midddleware-for-connect-express-js.html for more info on writing custom middleware.

Comment: thanks..does this add to the processing time/performance..can it not be 1 time loading...as the application get started or better would if there was a macro..as it just couple of lines in between logic in the routes...

Comment: The extra processing time is very negligible; I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out
[reshelper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reshelper)

```
npm i reshelper
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly your use case but you may want to use a middle ware.

Some examples defined here: http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-write-midddleware-for-connect-express-js.html but you can have a function with req and res as argument, called at each requests.

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello!');
});
```

You also have access to a third argument to pass the hand to the next middle ware:

```
function(req, res, next) {
    if (enabled && banned.indexOf(req.connection.remoteAddress) > -1) {
        res.end('Banned');
    }
    else { next(); }
}
```

Comment: In a route app.get '/something',(req,res)-> sendJsonErr('some error') unless checkSomething ...this would be in many routes..I want to avoid repeating the code..it is more of a macro(3 or 4 lines of codes) rather than a middleware

Comment: A middleware it's actually just a function called before the route in every requests. Like a filter if you prefer. It's even often a favourite choice to deal with error handling or logging. It's ok to use that for a few lines of codes. This will avoid code repetition

Comment: The only caveat is that is effectively called at every requests, so you have to find a way to bypass your code quickly if the request is suitable for you